# How do I uninstall Vagrant from Chocolatey?

Tags: vagrant, uninstallation, chocolatey

I installed Vagrant from Chocolatey and am now trying to remove it.  I run the command

```
choco uninstall vagrant -a
```

Chocolatey says it removed the application though it remains in the list of applications under Chocolatey

```
choco list --local-only
```

What do I need to do to remove this application from the Chocolatey list?  I have already removed the application from the computer using Control Panel.

Chocolatey version v0.9.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clear that [this package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vagrant) does not have [an uninstall script](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vagrant#comment-1720757516). Chocolatey should at least remove the managed package installation folder. It would leave the application behind in the Programs and Features applet of the Control Panel. You rightly uninstalled it there manually.

Newer versions of Chocolatey are supposed to handle automatically uninstalling at least MSI installers. You might explore the [`autoUninstaller`](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsUninstall) feature.

Your choices now are kind of limited:

- Try forcing the uninstall (or reinstalling/uninstalling w/force):

  ```
  PS> choco uninstall vagrant -force
  ```
- Manually remove the package install folder:

  ```
  PS> rm $ENV:chocolateyInstall\lib\vagrant* -recurse -force
  ```

Comment: Thank you, using choco uninstall vagrant -force removed it.

Comment: Yeah, things are going to be a bit weird as all of the old Chocolatey packages, without uninstallers, get updated or interact with the latest Chocolatey uninstall features.

Comment: I have used packages without uninstallers before. This is the first time I have ran into an issue where the app wasn't removed from the Chocolatey installed list

Comment: Yeah, it usually "just works." Unfortunately, we can't go back and capture the `-debug` log for that uninstall. It's one of those one-time things :)